# How to make DIV background a solid color, with a img as the border?

Tags: html, css

I have a div in the center of my page that i would like to have a white background in the center, and then, well, say you took 10px around all the edges of a appropriately sized picture, and put it on the edges of the white so basically its a white background, but with the full sized image only showing through the outside 10px.

Everything i have tried with the border-image property family doesnt seem to do what i want, it only puts the picture i want in every corner of what would be a border.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to put div into div. The first div is bigger, his background is your picture, and it has got padding=10px. The second one is smaller and contains white background.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the div with position `relative` and put your image in it. Secondly put the mask in pseudo `:before` or `:after` and give it position `absolute` with `top`/ `right`/ `bottom`/ `left` equal to each other such as 60px and style it.

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-image: url(http://placehold.it/400x400/4aa3df);
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative
}

div:before {
  content:'';
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 60px;
  left: 60px;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 60px;
  background-color: #eee;
  z-index: 9999
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

background-clip + padding or border or both should do with a gradient to draw the plain color:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip

```css
body, p , div {
  background:linear-gradient(white,white), url(http://lorempixel.com/300/300/abstract/10) center;
 /* background-size:auto auto,cover;*/
  background-clip : content-box, border-box;
  margin:1em;
  padding:1em;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 3px, inset 0 0 0 3px red ;/* borders needs to be used for demo, this fakes one outside and inside */
  min-height:30px;
  text-align:center;
  }
p {
  padding:0;
 
  border:solid 1em transparent 
    }
body {
  
  border:solid 1em transparent
    }
html {
  background:gray;
```

```html
body: 1em padding + 1em border. <b>Notice where stands inset red shadow in containers</b>
<div>div: 1em padding </div>
<p>p: 1em border</p>
```